# How can I get the full source (HTML) of a web-page with vba?

Tags: html, asp.net, excel, vba, web

I am trying to automate a work task using excel VBA. I can't seem to get all the source code. I created this simple code to test it.

```
dim IE as object
Dim S as String
Set IE = CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.application")
Call LocateOpeGSAPage (IE)
DIM htmlDoc as HTMLDocument
set htmldoc = IE.Document
s = htmldoc.body.innerHTML
```

It pulls some HTML code that is a few lines long from my company's webpage.

If it is helpful here is what happens if I try to get the source code manually:
When I manually right click on the web page and then click "View Source" that data from my company's web page that I mentioned above is what pulls up in the source code window under a tab called "Default.aspx"

However, If I manually right click on the webpage a second time and click on "view source" then a new tab opens in the source code window titled "DesktopDefault{1}" and it displays all the source code that I need.

How can I get to that source code using VBA? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to my own question. I didn't really need to grab the HTML source code, so I decided to change my code to reference Selenium because my true goal was to be able to locate the elements. I then used "SwitchtoFrame" to call the frame that had the elements that I wanted to access. When I didn't use "SwitchtoFrame" I was getting a NoSuchElement error so switchtoframe was the true problem solver for me.

```
Dim ch As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim Elements As Selenium.WebElements
Dim Element As Selenium.WebElement
Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
Dim url As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


ch.Get "https://abak.abch.net/cge/", Raise:=False
ch.SwitchToFrame ("MainFrame")

ch.FindElementById("ctl04_txtUsername").SendKeys "adock"
ch.FindElementById("ctl04_txtPassword").SendKeys "B12G89#F"

ch.FindElementById("ctl04_btnLogin").ClickDouble}
```